# Generate HTML files using XML configuration

Tags: java, xml, ant, build, transformation

My target is to assemble a static web site that has a lot of repeating code. Now, I could use JSP includes for that purpose. But the site will be modified infrequently and under very heavy load, also using features like gzip and I don't need the complications.

My idea is to put up a build process with some tool like ant, That build process will concatenate all HTML pieces, preprocess HTML, JS, CSS with minifier and finally apply gzip.
I want an XML configuration that will define the parts that need to go in every html page and their order.

I need advice on ant or any similar tool; how to approach the configuration, any external tools that will help? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look for static site generators like Jekyll (Ruby) or Hyde (Python).

Comment: Also check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186290/best-static-website-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) is perfectly suited to transform XML into another format like HTML.

You can download [Apache Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) to give it a try. **Ant** has support for [XSLT processing](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html).

Comment: I also prefer XSLT. ant has build in support for XSLT with the style tag. I found a good example of how to do what I need here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/index.html And I decided to use Saxon, it supports XSLT 2.0 and it is faster

Answer (score 1):

In the java world, you can take a look at [Apache Forrest](http://forrest.apache.org/), which precisely do that kind of things.

In other worlds, there also exist [webgen](http://webgen.rubyforge.org), which is a competent Ruby site builder.

I also vaguey remember there are other alternatives, but i can't find back their name.

Comment: I looked at Apache forest, I think it is too complex for my purpose. Thanks!